# How to determine null session attribute using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I've set a session that controls the menu based on the role of every user... Now for example I have this

```
<c:set var="role" scope="session" value='<%=((Long) session.getAttribute("role")).longValue()%>' />
<c:if test="${role == 121}">
        <div id="menu">
            <span class="menu-header">Registration</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registration/organization-registry">Organization Registry</a></li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </c:if>

<div id="menu">
                <span class="menu-header">Directory</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Organization</a></li>


                </ul>
            </div>
```

Now what if I want to go to that page without logging in? I tried to go to that page without logging in but `NullPointetExcepetion` was encountered basically because I don't have any session stored in the role. I set every session when the user logs in. When not logging in I want to view menu that does not need any role... For example I redirect to that page with one link that can be viewed by other.

How can I still view the directory menu when I'm not logged in?

Comment: Less is more.  Let JSTL walk up each scope without referencing the session scope - remove the c:set call.

Comment: It's not exactly JSTL who's doing that. To learn what JSTL exactly is, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `<c:set>` line altogether. You don't need it. EL `${}` already searches for attribtues in page, request, session and application scope. The NPE is caused because you invoked `longValue()` on `null`.

Remember: you should never mix oldschool *scriptlets* `<% %>` with modern EL `${}`. That makes no sense. You'll only confuse yourself.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)